# Restart setInterval inside loop after clearInterval

Tags: javascript

I'm making an animated progress bar with `setInterval` that will call the function `animate` to increase the width of the `.bar`. I need to stop the `setInterval` when the counter is 100/the width of the bar is 100% and restart it again for the next bar.

The problem is that the `for` loop seems immediately called the function three times (because the length of the bar is 3) instead of waiting for the current bar to be finished and then only resetting the counter to 0 and restarting the `setInterval` for the next bar...

I've been struggling with this for about an hour, please help.

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  let intervalId,
  counter = 0;
  function animate() {
    if(counter >= 100) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      counter++;
      items[i].style.width = `${counter}%`;
    }
  }
    
  intervalId = setInterval(animate, 10);
}
```

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}

.item {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
}

.bar {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop. `setInterval()` does the iteration.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please give an example because I don't understand how to target the next bar like `items[i]` and start the `setInterval` without the `for` loop...

Comment: A quick and dirty fix is to delay the interval for bars 2 and 3: https://jsfiddle.net/6wvc9dtp/

Comment: Here's a proper, Promise based way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/8kqjobfs/

Comment: @ChrisG The second of your answer seems too professional for me now and I don't understand fully...LOL...The first one seems simpler but why it's not a 'proper' and 'promise' way in your opinion...You should provide an official answer explaining these instead of comments...I really thank you and appreciate your help...

Comment: Relying on timers working 100% is not recommended. It makes no difference here but is bad practice in general. This is primarily about starting a new interval when the previous is cleared, which can be achieved by moving the interval inside a function and simply calling it again after clearing the current interval. I also basically never post answers because every question at this point is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code for a single progress bar in a function, which takes the item index as an argument. Then when you reach the end of one progress bar, you can stop it and call the function for the next one.

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

function progressBar(i) {
  if (i < items.length) {
    let intervalId,
      counter = 0;

    function animate() {
      if (counter >= 100) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        progressBar(i + 1);
      } else {
        counter++;
        items[i].style.width = `${counter}%`;
      }
    }

    intervalId = setInterval(animate, 10);
  }
}

progressBar(0);
```

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}

.item {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
}

.bar {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice JavaScript Recursion, I didn't know I can do this before you provide this answer.